# How to limit ggplot2 results

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset of cars sales. I want to return the top 10 most sold car labels and I don't know how to do this. The plot is working fine so far, but I don't know how to limit this.

```r
# install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

carsDataset <- read.csv("cars_train.csv", 
                        sep = "\t", 
                        na.strings = "", 
                        fileEncoding = "UTF16LE")

cars <- data.frame(marcas = carsDataset$marca)

ggplot(cars, 
       aes(x = reorder(marcas, marcas, function(x) + length(x)))) +
  geom_bar(fill = 'steelblue') + 
  ggtitle(label = "Marcas", 
          subtitle = "As marcas de carro mais vendidas") + 
  labs(x = "Marcas", 
       y = "Vendas") + 
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: If you construct the table yourself (with `dplyr::count()`, you can then select the rows you want your self with `dplr::slice_max()`, then use `geom_col()` to do the plotting

Comment: It would be easier to help if you edit your question to make a reproducible